# Comparing Datagridview row data with multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using C# WindowsForms,

I have 2 Datagridviews, each Datagridview has 2 columns.

I want to compare DT1 with DT2 rows, if DT1 (Col1 and Col2) is found in DT2 row (Col1 and Col2) then DT1 row and DT2 row will be removed/deleted.

[Diagram of the explained above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYMKI.png)

[Error Row index provided is out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLExx.jpg)

```
Code Start Here
{
        bool MatchFound = false;

        List<int> IndexToRemoveFromGrid = new List<int>();


        //Loop Table 1 and get Row Values for Col1+Col2
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewRow T1Col1row = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index];
            DataGridViewRow T1Col2row = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index];
            string T1Col1RX = (string)T1Col1row.Cells[0].Value + (string)T1Col1row.Cells[1].Value;

            MatchFound = false;

            //Loop Table 2 and get Row Values for Col1+Col2
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rowT2 in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewRow T2Col1row = dataGridView2.Rows[rowT2.Index];
                DataGridViewRow T2Col2row = dataGridView2.Rows[rowT2.Index];
                string T2Col1RX = (string)T2Col1row.Cells[0].Value + (string)T2Col1row.Cells[1].Value;

                if (MatchFound == false)
                {
                    //Compare Table 1 RX to Table2 RX , If matched then deleted row on both sides
                    if (String.Compare(T1Col1RX, T2Col1RX, false) == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Index > -1 && rowT2.Index > -1)
                        {
                            IndexToRemoveFromGrid.Add(row.Index);
                        }
                        MatchFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= IndexToRemoveFromGrid.Count(); i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Datagridviews have collections of data, just compare contents and remove the unncessary from the containers.

Comment: I wrote this however i am facing an issue with index value, return -1 and exception

Comment: What exception did you get and when it occured?

Comment: I solved the exception, i had something wrong with the loop, however i fixed it. My issue now is that when i first run it removes rows and when i run again it will remove more rows even that they are not the same value

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the data bounded to the DataGrid, that will be better than accessing the properties of the grid itself.

Comment: I managed to get to a good point however i am facing an error , click on the error link i have attached a screenshot. Now i know that every time i delete the index number the whole index number will be shifted, for example i have 1324 Index and the error happens on 662 which is half so i don't know how to solve it yet, a little help would be great